# Enumerable#each_slice in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to push through this code. I want to reorganize an array into slices of 2 and then sort each slice alphabetically.

This is the code I’ve written but it’s showing up as failure.

```ruby
def sorted_pairs(array)
  sorted_pairs = []
  array.each_slice(2).to_a { |group| sorted_pairs << group.sort }
end
```

Comment: To get the above code running, remove `.to_a` and return `sorted_pairs` at the end of your method. This can be further shortened by using `map` as shown in the answer below.

Comment: For future questions, it would be helpful to demonstrate an example of input and desired output. You may get a novel approach you didn't consider.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea using `each_slice`. What `each_slice` gives you (assuming you don't give it a block) is an enumerator, and you want to do some work to each element of that enumerator. In your case, that "work" is sorting the sublist. When we want to do something for each element of a list and produce a new list as result, that's a [`map`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) operation.

```
array.each_slice(2).map { |group| group.sort }
```

And `{ |group| group.sort }` is just a named method call, so it can be shortened using `Symbol#to_proc`.

```
array.each_slice(2).map(&:sort)
```